# Ubuntu login doesn't do anything. Left with only a cursor and background

Tags: unity, login, kde, lightdm, kde4

I've tried with lightdm, kdm, unity and kde4. Same results. I enter my password, hit enter and the login menu disappears, leaving just the cursor and greeter background. The window manager, whichever it is, simply doesn't start.

How can I fix it and which log files should I be looking at to track down this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by removing the entire `~/.cache` directory. I read somewhere that it could be a permissions issue with a file there. Perhaps from running something as root/sudo. Still not sure of the right way to debug the problem, was just trial and error.